# Need to use only 2 attributes from a constructor

Tags: java, object, inheritance, attributes, associations

I am creating an object "Person" which has 4 atributes: String name, String lastName, char gender and int age. This class already has a constructor that is working fine which extends information to other objects I have.

However, I now have a particular object which is called "birthdayBoy" and it is only going to need 2 of these attributes plus 2 new atributes I am adding to it (String birthdayCity, String school). If I inherit the constructor from the "Person" object, it will ask me for the chain of 4 attributes (String,String,char,int) and that won't work for me. I have not created the Main class to call and test the objects, so far I have only created the classes which contain these objects and the reason why is because I want to know if this is something I will need to fix on the class itself or I should create an additional class that inherits only 2 of those attributes from the "Person" class.

Any help is apprecciate it.

Comment: You could create a constructor in `Person` that only has the two required parameters for `BirthdayBoy` and then in `BirthdayBoy` extend it with the 2 extra required parameters

Comment: If 2 fields from a super class are not needed then this sounds like a bad design choice. Conceptually inheriting a class means enriching it and specializing it, not the opposite.

Comment: @kalenpw Thanks! I think that solves part of my problem. Now here is the thing, if I create another constructor  that will get oly the 2 parameters and I have the other one with 4, would it create a problem if they are call with the same name? Should I change that in order to call it on the other class?

Comment: @InusualWhisperSInclair no, constructors 
c̶a̶n̶ ̶h̶a̶v̶e̶ ̶t̶h̶e̶ ̶s̶a̶m̶e̶  **must have ** the same name as long as their parameters are different.

Comment: No, it's not that they "can have the same name", rather they ***MUST*** have the same name. A constructor name must match the class's name exactly.

Comment: @Jack yes I know it does nto sound like the best design option. This is a test that was given to us and it could be that I am interpreting it on the wrong way, but one of the objects is supposed to use only 2 attributes which have the same name than the "Person" object (name, lastName) and is not needing the rest. I was initially thinking that this might had to do with the concept of association but I am not entirely sure...

Comment: Thank you. Yeap I knew they must have the same name, reason why I ask if that would create a conflict or not at the time that I call it from the other class. I just wanted to make sure I was not utilizing another constructor unnecessarily.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a constructor in `Person` that only has the two required parameters for `BirthdayBoy` and then in `BirthdayBoy` extend it with the 2 extra required parameters

```
public class Person{
    String firstName;
    String middleName;
    String lastName;
    int age;

    public Person(String fName, String lName){
        firstName = fname;
        lastName = lName;
    }

    //Your 4 parameters constructor with the same name
    public Person(String fName, String mName, String, lName, int newAge){
        firstName = fName;
        middleName = mName;
        lastName = lName;
        age = newAge;
    }
}

public class BirthdayBoy extends Person{
    String birthMonth;
    int birthYear;

    public BirthdayBoy(String fName, String lName, String bMonth, int bYear){
        super(fName, lName);
        birthMonth = bMonth;
        birthYear = bYear;
    }

}
```

Comment: Perfect thanks! That solves the doubt that I was having. I will creating the 2nd constructor that receives only those 2 parameters

Answer (score 0):

In your base class "Person", have 2 constructors. One takes 4 parameters and the other accepts 2 parameters. You can have as many overloaded constructors as you choose.